# row_array() not working in codeigniter library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have create a function to fetch user data in codeigniter in library. Using this function row_array() or row() function is not working. When I print $this->CI->db->last_query(); function and that query is running properly inside phpmyadmin. My code is given below.

```
    $result = $this->CI->db->select('`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `access`')
                ->from('HM_admin')
                ->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)))
                ->get()
                ->row_array();

    echo $this->CI->db->last_query();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result); exit;
```

Sorry for bad english...

Comment: `$result->row_array();`

Comment: This is also not working..

Comment: @HiraSingh try this `$this->db->select('`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `access`');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('HM_admin',array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)));
        return $query->row_array();`

Comment: This is also not working. In this library nothing is working like row_array(); or row(); or result_array(); or result(); etc etc... but queries are being printed properly.

Comment: @HiraSingh what value gets printed in `print_r($result)`

Answer (score 0):

@Hira Singh

just remove `CI` form from your code and try this code.

```
$result = $this->db->select('`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `access`')
            ->from('HM_admin')
            ->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)))
            ->get()
            ->row_array();

echo $this->db->last_query();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result); exit;
```

Comment: My function inside a library and $this->CI is my instance. I can't remove this

Answer (score 0):

add false in second parameter of select as

```
$this->CI->db->select('`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `username`, `email`, `access`',False)->from('HM_admin')->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)))->get()->row_array();
```

or write like this
add false in second parameter of select as

```
 $this->CI->db->select('id,firstname,lastname,username,email,access')->from('HM_admin')->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)))->get()->row_array();
```

try this.

```
$this->CI->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
$this->CI->db->select('id,firstname,lastname,username,email,access')->from('HM_admin')->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => md5($password)))->get()->row_array();
$this->CI->db->_protect_identifiers=true;
```